# Какую связь использовать в SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть задание: приложение, позволяющее арендовать квартиры. Есть база данных postgresql. Создал схему task и в ней 3 таблицы:

1. house с атрибутами: id (первый ключ), город, улица, комната, цена, описание, статус (арендована или нет, здесь ли её нужно вообще вставлять или нужна отдельная таблица с текущим состоянием?), время длительности аренды (тот же вопрос как и про статус).
2. landlord (арендодатель): id (первый ключ), имя, фамилия, телефон, почта, кол-во квартир.
3. tenant (арендатор): id (первый ключ), имя, фамилия, телефон, почта.

Конкретно по вопросам:

1. Как понимать какую связь использовать?
2. Как понять, что данные подходят в эту таблицу? Понимаю, что достаточно логично подумать, но в моём случае про статус квартиры интересно.
3. Названия таблиц и их атрибутов должны быть с большой буквы или с маленьких?
4. Правильно ли составил многие ко многим?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как арендодатели связаны с квартирами ? Логично было бы в квартире хранить id арендодателя. Если конечно не рассматривать ситуацию, что квартиру может кто то купить и то же предоставлять в аренду, тогда арендодатель сменится. И тут надо смотреть для чего он вообще используется, достаточно ли только текущего или нужна история. никакого количества квартир у арендодателя быть не должно, его всегда можно по квартирам посчитать

Comment: Как арендаторы связаны с квартирами ? У вас сейчас вообще никак. значит нужна отдельная таблица связи арендаторов с квартирами: арендатор, квартира, дата заезда, дата выезда. Когда она у вас будет вам уже не нужны никакие статусы и длительности аренды у квартиры

Comment: Исправил замечания. Создал таблицу под названием status, которая в себе будет иметь перечисленные вами данные. Верно понимаю, что она нам нужна для того, чтобы понимать то, занята квартира или нет. Нам необходимо все поля сделать primary key? Теперь мы связали арендатора и квартиру с помощью статуса. А хозяина квартира необходимо связать с квартирой, так или нет?

Comment: primary key в таблице один. и это обычно id. это поле по которому как раз идет связь из других таблиц. Скорее квартиру с хозяином, а не хозяина с квартирой.

Comment: Понял, просто я видел, что иногда делают несколько primary key в таблице, которая связывает одну с другой. Теперь мне нужно создать новую таблицу под названием, например, house_landlord, которая будет иметь атрибуты: id квартиры, имя хозяина, а что-то ещё нужно? А нужно ли это вообще делать, если мы уже в таблице house, как вы предложили, прописали всю информацию о квартире и её собственнике?

Comment: Если у вас в квартире, как я предложил, есть id собственника то дополнительная таблица для связи вам не нужна. Если вам не надо что бы у квартиры было несколько собственников

Comment: Да, понял, хорошо. У меня теперь столько таблиц, сколько было и +1 для связи. Правильно понимаю, что эта связь будет многие ко многим

Comment: да, та что в отдельной таблице квартира-арендатор это многие ко многим

Comment: @Mike Можете посмотреть, правильно ли составил таблицы?

Comment: Да, выглядит неплохо. Только в таблице status нет первичного ключа. Без первичного ключа довольно сложно удалить/изменить конкретную запись. Разве что указывать в where все поля. Думаю можно первичным сделать связку из полей id_house, startDate. Они конечно не обеспечат правильной уникальности (что бы физически невозможно было внести в бд пересекающиеся интервалы дат по одной квартире) но сделают небольшой шаг в этом направлении, по крайней мере нельзя будет выполнить два заезда в одну квартиру в один день.

Comment: И лично я бы уже начал задумываться не объединить ли landlord и tenant в одну таблицу. В реальном мире сущьность то одна "человек" (пока не рассматриваем что квартиру могут сдавать/снимать организации). И один и тот же человек может как сдавать одну квартиру, так и брать в аренду другую. И было бы логично, что все его персональные данные лежат в БД в одном экземпляре. Но понятно что у сдающих и снимающих квартиры со временем могут найтись разные атрибуты, уникальные только для данного типа и надо будет думать как их хранить. И заодно можно будет контролировать что чел не снимает сам у себя

Comment: Добавил первичный ключ в таблице status, связал startDate и id house. А по какому параметру тогда мне привязать status и tenant? Я связал id tenant и status tenant. Думал оставить только USER, но как-то ведь нужно потом будет различать кто подключил свою квартиру к нам в сервис, а кто просто арендует. Решил для упрощения так оставить.

Comment: Ещё самый важный вопрос: как эти связи вообще работают? Понимаю, что у нас сейчас они настроились, теперь при добавлении данных будут измениться те таблицы, которые связаны

Comment: при добавлении ничего изменяться само не будет. связь только обеспечивает что вы не сможете записать скажем в таблицу status несуществующий id квартиры. Связи они больше для вас нужны, что бы выдели куда что писать

Comment: @Mike я всё же прислушался и объединил в одну таблицу арендатора и арендодателя. Создам таблицу юзер и потом с помощью секьюрити начну выдавать роли. Но вот тогда не совсем понимаю какие атрибуты им можно добавить, что можно реализовать в таком случае? Хотел сделать "добавить квартиру", а второму снять, но тогда не совсем понимаю суть этих атрибутов. Как они вообще будут выглядеть? Какие параметры принимать? Boolean?

Comment: Да, вполне можно два признака "Может сдавать", "Может снимать" типа boolean если ваша БД поддерживает такой тип. ну или любой его заменяющий. Хотя второй тип может и не нужен, зачем кому то запрещать снимать квартиры

Comment: @Mike Ещё потревожу, а арендодатель - квартира. Что это за связь? Я мечусь между один ко многим, а также многие ко многим. Потому что один собственник может иметь несколько квартир, а у нескольких квартир может быть несколько собственников.

Comment: один (арендодатель) в многим (квартирам). потому что у одной квартиры не может быть более одного арендодателя. многие-ко-многим работают так что и у одной стороны может быть много и у другой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте объясню как строить схему базы данных исходя из сущностей. Сущностью будем считать запись/одна строчка в произвольной таблице.

Какие существуют связи между двумя таблицами.

1. Один к одному. Применяется в случаях когда одной сущности может соответствовать единственная сущность из другой таблицы. (Обычно применяется для хранения дополнительной информации к основной таблице. Пример. House (id, name) и HouseInfo(id, houseId, address, numberOfRooms, square ....)). Зачем разделять? Вам не всегда известны его детали, и зачастую нет большой необходимости.
2. Один ко многим. Когда одной сущности может соответствовать много сущностей из другой таблицы, которым соответствует только одна запись. House(id, name) , HouseStatus (id, houseId, statusId, start, end). У дома много различных состояний но каждое состояние соответствует только одному дому.
3. Много ко многим. Когда много различных сущностей соответствуют многим другим. Делается это обычно в 3 таблицы. House(id, name), HouseLandlord (id, houseId, landlordId, startDate, endDate, ...), Landlord (id, name,...). Когда две независимые сущности соединяются через промежуточную.

Решать какую связь использовать очень просто. Описываете каждую сущность как независимую и добавляете связи "если они конечно нужны". Если можно установить прямую связь добавляете колонку id зависимой получили один ко многим (в частном случае один к одному) если нет то добавляете промежуточную таблицу с id из обеих таблиц и получили много ко многим. Это обычная практика.

Но существуют также более сложные схемы когда приходится нарушать 3ю нормальную форму, но это уже совсем другая задача.